# How to implement the seeking functionality in HTTP video loading

Tags: http, video, streaming

I currently have a working client-server model that can load and play a video file back, which is located on the server. The server itself is able to process Range requests and send back the corresponding video data. Now I want to implement a seeking functionality so the user can "jump" ahead of the already buffered video part, but I have zero clue on how to do so, not even the theoretical strategy. Therefore I have two major questions:

1. How do i calculate the byte offset from the time the user jumps to? There are so many factors that modify the size in bytes per minute video, for exampe width, height, bitrate, samplerate, codecs...
2. How do i fill the "gap" between the part I already buffered and the newly fetched video segment? I assume that I cannot just fill it up with zeros, since it might cut off some important data from the video segment.

For the client side implementation, I use a MediaSource object and append my data to its SourceBuffer. Maybe this info is important on how the data has to be appended.